# If I bought the Super Luigi U DLC on my Super Mario Bros. U disk, if I sell it, will the customer have the DLC?

Tags: wii-u, new-super-mario-bros-u, new-super-luigi-u

I bought the Super Luigi U thing, and I want to sell it now. Will the DLC be on the customers game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how DLC works. The data on the game disc is not and can not be altered. When you purchase DLC (or, really, anything from the E-Shop) it is registered to your Nintendo Network ID, and downloaded to your *console*. No data is added to the disc.

If you were to sell the game disc, the DLC would not go with the disc, as it is connected to your NNID. Further; you would have the DLC with no way to play it because you lack the game associated with it (However, were you to purchace a new copy of "Super Mario Bros. U", your DLC would be available again.

The only way to sell the game ***with*** the DLC would be to sell your entire console (along with your NNID, other E-shop purchaces, etc).

Comment: Got it, thanks! You just saved me a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

No. Super Luigi U is content saved to your system, not to the Super Mario Bros U disc. The buyer will only receive Super Mario Bros U, unless you also sell them your Wii U.